# How to solve $a^3+2b^3+6c^3=380$ for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

According to computer calculations, the integer solution is $(x, y, z)=(6, 1, 3)$ only.

Comment: I hardly believe that this equation can be solved in an elementary way. There may be some solution with $a,b,c$ very large.

Comment: @Crostul it's an elliptic curve, so there will be some algorithm to find all solutions. I don't want to do it, though.

Comment: By the way, other solutions are $(a,b,c)=(18,-17,9)$ and $(a,b,c)=(60,1,-33)$, found with brute force.

Comment: Another one is $(a,b,c)=(180,-17,-99)$.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response to the question !

Comment: Why did the computer(Wolfram alpha) give the wrong answer...?

Comment: I think (6,1,3) is the only solution with positive integers. If you only want positive solutions, they can be found with elementary means.

Comment: It took me about a minute of calculations to get those solutions. Wolfram Alpha simply stops itself when calculations become too heavy, so that it finds only small solutions.

Comment: I will try this problem again with only positive integer solution.
Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: If only positive solutions are allowed, the problem is trivial and can quickly be done by brute force. The hard part is to find all solutions over the integers. Can this really be solved with methods of elliptic curves although the exponent $3$ appears three times ?

Comment: @Peter I don't know much about elliptic curves...